# xcode encrypt sqlite or plist

Tags: ios, sqlite, encryption, sqlcipher

Hi, I created an iOS book and dictionary application. I used SQLITE database for this Apps, but problem is people can extract ipa's file and can use my database file. Is it possible to encrypt `SQLITE` or `PLIST` data. Or is there any other solution for this problem ?

Comment: have you looked already into http://sqlcipher.net ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can use SQl Cipher  for resolve this problem you encrypted your data using this 
for more detail of sql cypher
refer this link of cipher http://sqlcipher.net/design/

Link help you to set Up cipher in xcode

http://sqlcipher.net/ios-tutorial

if you want to implement cipher with ios you can get reference form these 
links

https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher

and

https://github.com/sqlcipher/SQLCipherManager

hope this may help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: I think SQl Cipher is not free. Is it free?

Comment: yes,SQL Cipher is Open source  and free : refer this http://sqlcipher.net/about/ on that first line "SQLCipher is an open source library that provides transparent, secure 256-bit AES encryption of SQLite database files."